# High Dynamic Range (HDR) from exposure bracketing of grayscale images

Tags: matlab, grayscale, hdrimages, hdr

I have one question about High Dynamic Range (HDR) images. I want to creat a high dynamic range image from exposure bracketing of grayscale images using matlab. Matlab only support creating HDR image from RBG images. I did google search but there is not many results that related to my topic. Can you advise me some papers or algorithms that could hepl me out.

thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What about replacing grayscale image to RGB image? I haven't used HDR modules, but it maybe works.

```
rgbImg = zeros(size(grayImg,1), size(grayImg,2), 3); 
rgbImg(:,:,1)=grayImg; 
rgbImg(:,:,2)=grayImg; 
rgbImg(:,:,3)=grayImg;
```

Answer (score 0):

The HDR Toolbox for MATLAB supports building greyscale images, please have a look at:
https://github.com/banterle/HDR_Toolbox

or

http://www.advancedhdrbook.com

It also supports SIFT and WARD alignment, if you have not use a tripod for capturing images.